# Showing Error: mysqli::real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'192.188.145.163' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, access-denied

This is a codeigniter project. my given database information is right.It works perfectly in localhost. But after uploading my project in hosting site, it still shows an 'access denied' error.

This is my database:

```
 $db['default'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'telihatyhighschool.edu.bd',
    'username' => 'db_username',
    'password' => 'db_password',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array() ,
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Read the mysql documantatio how you add a user to your database https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Comment: As above comment suggests your user dont have enough previliges

Comment: @MamunSabuj is this loaclhost database??

Comment: But I used All previlige checkbox.So I think there is no reason to don't have enough previliges.

Comment: are you running on your loaclhost ??

Comment: It works perfectly in localhost.But after uploading in my hosting site, it shows access denied error.

Comment: if your database is on localhost, and your php script is on remote location, then you should allow access to your mysql port on local machine.

Comment: is your hosting server is Linux host ??

Comment: hosting is done on cpaneel??

Comment: yes, hosting is done on cpanel

Comment: Your host starts with blank space? Also you have sufficient one quote infront username string.

Answer (score 4):

In cpannel actually username and database name has cpanel username prefix eg

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; //literaly put localhost
$db['default']['username'] = 'cpanelusername_root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'cpanelusername_db name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; ///use this extension
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

in more simple words

```
Host = localhost (literally put localhost)
Database name = (cpanelUsername_databaseName)
Database username = (cpanelUsername_databaseUsername)
Database password = (******)
```

**NOTE:**
When connecting to a database, you need to ensure that:

1. You've created a database
2. You've created a database username
3. You've assigned that user with privileges to your database

Your MySQL connections may use 127.0.0.1 or the IP address of your server, and MySQL will reject the connection if access isn't granted for the specific IP address used.

**Verify the permission tables (reloading grants if required) on the server and that you're connecting to**

Regrant Preveliges by :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* to 'user'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY '*UserPass*';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting server is Linux,

Change `hostname` value to `localhost`

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'XXXXXXXX',
    'database' => 'mydbname',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array() ,
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: it works perfectly in localhost. But shows error after uploading my project in hosting site.

Comment: what is your hosting provide ??

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have solved this problem changing:

```
$db['default'] = array('dsn' => '','hostname' => 'telihatyhighschool.edu.bd',
```

to:

```
$db['default'] = array('dsn' => '','hostname' => 'localhost',
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but all the error are resolved by adding privileges to that user

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the plain password with no special characters, below is the example:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'password',
    'password' => 'Mynewpass@756',
    'database' => 'database_name',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding a User under Privileges for the database.
This User should have the same values as database.php:

```
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

1. create a new database from cpanel
2. create a new username
3. assigned that user with privileges to your database
4. modify file database.php with new information database

public_html/application/config/database.php

5. export database from your old hosting cpanel - option phpmyadmin
6. import database to you new hosting cpanel- option phpmyadmin
7. DONE

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I had codeigniter project live on my server.

**Solution:**

In **File Manager** in codeigniter project  `public_html/your_project_name/application/config/database.php`

I added the password which was missing. [ Password of user when you created it in **Cpanel -> MySQL Databases** ]

**Make sure you have assigned the database access to this user with all privileges and your configurations in `database.php` are correct.

Mine are:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME', //Ex- abcd.com
    'username' => 'USER_NAME_HERE',// CREATED IN CPANEL->MySQL Database
    'password' => 'PASSWORD_HERE', // PASSWORD OF ABOVE USER
    'database' => 'YOUR_DB_NAME',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```